# WPF toolkit Accordion theme

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to theme a WPF toolkit accordion control. I've looked in the WPF themes codeplex page but it doesn't have a theme for the accordion. So I took the accordion theme from the Silverlight themes and used that but it won't work. It doesn't throw any error. It's just stuck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same yesterday and it worked perfectly for me. What I made was copy/paste the theme to a new file in my project named "AccordionTheme.xaml" and I inserted it into my Control like this :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\AccordionTheme.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Maybe you have either done something wrong by copy/paste or maybe an error with inserting it into your control/window ?